# Laravel 7 Pass Data To Another Controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent, view, controller

I am currently thinking about a "problem" and I am somehow stuck.

This is my "show" function in my first controller.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $model1 = Model1::find($id);
    return view('models1.show',compact('model1'));
}
```

This is my route

```
<a href="{{ route('model2.create') }}" class="uk-button uk-button-text">Create Model2</a>
```

This is my "create" function in my second controller.

```
public function create()
{
    return view('model2.create');
}
```

There is a relationship between both models. Model1 hasOne Model2 - Model2 belongsTo Model1.
When I show data from model1 in my web app I have a button where I redirect to the create view for model2 and I want to pass the id from model1 to this view.

I did some research but I kind of overthink it. There are ways to pass it with session or a post request but I do not think that this is "state of the art".

What is the best way to pass the id from model1 to the create view for model2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your `routes/web.php` you define a route like this:

```
Route::get('/model2/create/{model1Id}', 'Model2Controller@create')->name('model2.create')
```

in your blade template you use:

```
{{ route('model2.create', ['model1Id' => $model1->id]) }}
```

And your `Model2Controller` looks like this:

```
public function create($model1Id) {
    // use $model1Id here
}
```

You can also use [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding) to save some lines of code:

```
// routes/web.php
Route::get('/model2/create/{model1}', 'Model2Controller@create')->name('model2.create')

// blade template
{{ route('model2.create', ['model1' => $model1]) }}

// Model2Controller
public function create(Model1 $model1) {
    // use $model1 directly, you don't have to do
    // $model1 = Model1::findOrFail($model1Id) first
}
```

Comment: You could make it more complete if you would include [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding) in your example ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer! I took a look at route model binding and solved it :)